# The property of a weakly convergent sequence in $\ell_p$

Tags: functional-analysis

I am stuck with the proof of the following statement:

> If $x_n\in l_p$, $1<p<\infty$, $x_n\rightharpoonup0$ and $||x_n||^p\geq c>0$, then there is a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ such that $\forall N$ $\left\|\sum\limits_{k=1}^Nx_{n_k}\right\|\geq C\cdot N^{1/p}$ with some $C>0$.

**Attempt.** First, we note that weak convergence in $l_p$ implies convergence in coordinates. Next, take $x_{n_1}=x_1$. Because the $||x_{n_1}||^p\geq c$ and $||x_{n_1}||<\infty$, then there is a number $m_1$ such that $\sum\limits_{k=m_1+1}^{\infty}|\xi_k^{n_1}|^p\leq\frac{c}{5}$ and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m_1}|\xi_k^{n_1}|^p\geq\frac{3c}{5}$. Due to coordinatewise convergence, $\xi_k^{n}\underset{n\to\infty}{\to}0$ for all $k$, therefore there is a number $n_2>n_1$ such that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m_1}|\xi_k^{n_2}|^p\leq\frac{c}{5}$, and then $\sum\limits_{k=m_1+1}^{\infty}|\xi_k^{n_2}|^p\geq\frac{4c}{5}$. So we can find the number $m_2>m_1$ such that $\sum\limits_{k=m_2+1}^{\infty}|\xi_k^{n_2}|^p\leq\frac{c}{5}$ and $\sum\limits_{k=m_1+1}^{m_2}|\xi_k^{n_2}|^p\geq\frac{3c}{5}$. Further, the process continues indefinitely. Represent the members of the found subsequence in the form: $$x_{n_1}=(\xi_1^{n_1},...,\xi_{m_1}^{n_1},0,0,...)+(0,...,0,\xi_{m_1+1}^{n_1},...)=a_1+b_1$$$$x_{n_2}=(0,...,0,\xi_{m_1+1}^{n_2},...,\xi_{m_2}^{n_2},0,0,...)+(\xi_1^{n_2},...,\xi_{m_1}^{n_2},0,...,0,\xi_{m_2+1}^{n_2},...)=a_2+b_2$$$$x_{n_3}=(0,...,0,\xi_{m_2+1}^{n_3},...,\xi_{m_3}^{n_3},0,0,...)+(\xi_1^{n_3},...,\xi_{m_2}^{n_3},0,...,0,\xi_{m_3+1}^{n_3},...)=a_3+b_3$$$$...$$
Then we get: $$\left\|\sum\limits_{k=1}^Nx_{n_k}\right\|=\|(a_1+...+a_N)+(b_1+...+b_N)\|\geq|\|a_1+...+a_N\|-\|b_1+...+b_N\||.$$ Next, evaluate: $\|a_1+...+a_N\|^p\geq N\cdot\frac{3c}{5}$. And with the $\|b_1+...+b_N\|$ I have problems. I want to $\|b_1+...+b_N\|^p\leq N\cdot\frac{2c}{5},$ and the statement will be proved. But I don’t see where this can come from. Maybe my construction was initially wrong and it was necessary to build the subsequence differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to use $x(i)$ for the $i$'th entry of $x \in \ell^p$.

I claim you can do this as long as  $0 < C < c^{1/p}$. Take $n_1 = 1$ and note that $\|x_{n_1}\| \ge C$.  Given $n_1, \ldots, n_N$ satisfying the inequality, let $y = \sum_{i=1}^N x_{n_i}$.  So $y \in \ell^p$ with
$\|y\| \ge C N^{1/p}$.   Let $P_M$ be the projection operator so that $(P_M x)(i) = x(i)$ for $i \le M$
and $(P_M x)(i) = 0$ for $i > M$.  Thus $\|x \|^p = \|P_M x\|^p + \|(I-P_M) x\|^p$.
Take $M$ so large that $\|(I-P_M) y\| < \delta$, where $\delta > 0$ is to be chosen later.  Since $x_n(i) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ for each $i$, we can take $n_{N+1}$ so large that $\|P_M x_{n_{N+1}}\| < \delta$.
 Thus 
$$\|y + x_{n_{N+1}}\|^p \ge (C N^{1/p} - 2 \delta)^p + (c^{1/p}-2\delta)^p$$
If $\delta$ is sufficiently small, the right side is greater than $C^p (N+1)$.

Comment: Can you please explain the last inequality? Why are there two terms on the right side?

Comment: The first term is a bound for $\|P_M (y + x_{n_{N+1}})\|^p$, the second a bound for 
$\|(I-P_M)(y+x_{n_{N+1}}\|^p$.

Comment: Excuse me. Can you tell me about a similar task: $x_n\in l_p$, $1<p<\infty$, $x_n\rightharpoonup0$ and $||x_n||\leq C$, then $\forall N$ $\left\|\sum\limits_{n=1}^Nx_{n}\right\|\leq C\cdot N^{1/p}$. Will the same technique work? I can’t figure out how to deal with $x_{n_{N+1}}$, he is now not selected, but set initially, therefore for him the condition $\|P_Mx_{n_{N+1}}\|<\delta$ not necessarily true. What can be done in this case? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: That "similar task" is certainly not true as stated.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wrote the condition incorrectly. It was necessary so: $\left\|\sum\limits_{n=1}^Nx_{n}\right\|\leq C_1\cdot N^{1/p}$ for some $C_1>0$.

Comment: Still not true (e.g. if $x_n = t_n x_1$ with $t_n \to 0$).  Do you want to take a subsequence?